# Liferay: Migrate Theme from 6.1 to 6.2

Tags: migration, themes, liferay

We want soon upgrade the portal from Liferay 6.1.30 GA3 to 6.2. The backend of portlets seem be simple to migrate. But the changes of theme technology is huge :) I mean the way to bootstrap is very welcome, but how is it with the migration of existing (6.1) theme?

Our theme based on standard Liferay 6.1 styled theme. However, I'm looking for some guideline how to migrate e.g. Liferay 6.1 classic theme to 6.2.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow Liferay Portal 6.2 Developer's Guide
https://www.liferay.com/zh/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/alloyui-2-0-bootstrap-migration-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-02-en

Answer (score 0):

As you said themes between 6.1 and 6.2 changed a lot. You maybe will be able to migrate a theme from the two versions, but you maybe won't get full bootstrap power.

When migrating from 6.0 ,6.1 to the 6.2 usually you should consider to built a new theme and maybe also to re-design your template to follow "mobile-first" approach of bootstrap.

Source: Liferay Symposium (Italy) 2013